# Adding an outlook email as attachment in Vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a requirement where I need to attach an email as attachment using visual force page i.e. I want to select an outlook email as an input from the visual force page and get it attached to a particular record on sales force.

If it is possible can I have the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the email in Outlook as .msg file and then upload as any other file using VF page. This [example](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/uploading-a-document-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller) show how to upload a file using VF.